# Extracting plain text from PostScript file via gsdll32.dll

Tags: delphi, pdf

Trying to extract plain text from a postscript file using **GhostScript ver 9.10 gsdll32.dll** file. Can't seem to get anything to work. Tried multiple variations.

```
{ extracts plain text from PostScript file via ps2ascii.ps }
procedure PS2TXT(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
var
  code:integer;
  instance: Pointer;
  argv: array of PAnsiChar;
  RunFile: string;
begin
RunFile:= ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'ps2ascii.ps';
  code := gsapi_new_instance(instance, nil);
  if code < 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Impossible to open an instance of ghostscript. Error code: '+IntToStr(code));
  try
    SetLength(argv, 8);
    argv[0] := PAnsiChar('-q -dNODISPLAY -dSAFER -dDELAYBIND ');
    argv[1] := PAnsiChar('-dWRITESYSTEMDICT ');
    argv[2] := PAnsiChar('-dSIMPLE ');
    argv[3] := PAnsiChar('-c save ');
    argv[4] := PAnsiChar('-f ' + RunFile);
    argv[5] := PAnsiChar(input);
    argv[6] := PAnsiChar('-c quit ');
    argv[7] := PAnsiChar('> ' + output + '.txt');
//  argv[7] := PAnsiChar('-sOutputFile='+ output + '.txt' );

    code := gsapi_init_with_args(instance, Length(argv), @argv[0]);
    if code < 0 then raise Exception.Create('ERROR: init_args: '+IntToStr(code));
    gsapi_exit(instance);
  finally
    gsapi_delete_instance(instance);
  end;
end;
```

The RunFile varibable just gets the current path from the running exe then appends to the ps2ascii.ps file.

Alternatively I would like to convert a PDF file to plain text file via the same ps2ascii.ps interpreter. The output needs to be in plain text so that I can parse through it extracting specific key fields, and then post it to a database. However, extracting text from a PDF via the TXTWRITE device seems to only work on some pdf files but not all. So doing it this way as a work around.
Anybody got any code that works with the DLL?

Comment: Minor update: got the export routine of PDF to PostScript file format working. But still haven't figured out the text filtering with ps2ascii.ps yet

Comment: Is there a text at all? can you select and copy text using PDF viewers like Sumatra, PDF XChange, etc ?

Comment: Actually yes, surprisingly. The PDF is generated by RICOH Aficio MP 5002. And just about every PDF to text extractor I've tried both free/trial can't extract it. There's not security bit enabled so my guess is that it was a screen dump and ran through the distiller. But upon converting to postscript all the data is there. I used PostScript studio to reconvert it back to PDF from postscript file, and it worked fine. I think its the proprietary ricoh distiller that's messing it up. Going to try recompiling to PDF via gsdll32 and then try the txtwrite device, to see if that corrected it.

Comment: It is typical to render text into curves abd vectors pictures. It might be to avoid copying and searching, or it might be just to avoid different fonts issues in WYSIFYG environments. OTOH i ain't sure if GhostScript/GhostView can do anythign but *rendering* the PDF, in other words converrting everything into pictures. There are some paid PDF components for Delphi and there are GPL sources of muPDF and SumatraPDf, dunno if you can make use of them...

Comment: Well if worse case scenario, the secretaries will have to enter the purchase order in manually. Just trying to make it a little easier on them. I thought about rendering the PDF to a high res PNG file and doing an OCR on it, but I already know thats going to be a nightmware on coding AND accuracy. But trying the simplest routes first.

Comment: Update #2, well as I had thought- ITS A FRIGGIN IMAGE FILE !!! So extracting text is out of the question. Will have to resort to OCR'ing the text out. More difficult, but still doable. But solved my original problem of getting the DLL connection working. Posting a class file for everyone to use that might have similar issues with using the GhostScript DLL.

Comment: FineReader made a spacial editions of their software to read screenshots and to read printed blankets filled by hands. Perhaps OCR can be done to be much better than "nightmare" especially if you can preset blanket templates. Unless some very exotic "decorative" fonts were used. Since this question turned into "How can i extract text fro mPDF file having no text inside" then perhaps the questions be closed as invalid? IF you're sure the PDF itself is an image, not just GhostScript's output of it.

Comment: Yeah my wording was a little poor with the question, now looking back on it. But my original issue/question was getting the correct parameters working with GhostScript DLL. That's resolved, so technically the question was answered. As for the OCR'ing [new direction now], I'm presently looking into all methods. Abby FineReader being one of them. But prefer it to be something in OCX or DLL format that I can call from code. Been playing with Tesseract 3.0 DLL last night and looks promising. It's reading it [exported png image from pdf], but need to fine tune it [train] yet.

Answer (score 1):

Other individuals who have STRUGGLED to get the right parameters to get GhostScript DLL working in Delphi may find this useful. It's quick and dirty, but works. Clean it up as you wish. ENJOY!

**GhostTools.pas Class file for GSDLL32.DLL**

```
// GhostTools.pas v.03, 12/20013, Marvi mail: phantomlord@embarqmail.com
//
// Open source, modify to whatever extent
// Class to interact with GhostScript gsdll32.dll for simple PDF manipulation
// i.e. PDF to Jpeg, PDF to PNG, PDF to PS, PDF to Text, PS to PDF, etc.
// Requires GhostScript GSDLL32.DLL to reside in .EXE project folder
// or at the very least somewhere your app can get to it.
// If you use the ps2ascii.ps interpreter, do same as well.
//
// include GhostTools in your uses section, and use as needed

unit GhostTools;

interface

uses SysUtils, gsapi; {gsapi.pas file required as well}

 procedure PDF2PNG(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
 {generates PNG image from PDF }

 procedure PDF2JPEG(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
 {generates JPEG image from PDF }

 procedure PDF2PS(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
 {generates PostScript file from PDF file }

 procedure PS2PDF(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
 {generates PDF file from PostScript file }

 procedure PDF2TXT(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
 {extracts plain text via TxtWrite device - Method #1 }

 procedure PDS2TXT(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
 {extract plain text via PostScript interpreter - Method #2 }

 function SlashSwap(PathVar: string): string;
 {exchange backslash for forward slash - unix style }

implementation

{ exchange backslash for forward slash - to unix path format }
{ resolves path issue in ps2ascii.ps running on Windows platform }
function SlashSwap(PathVar: string): string;
var tmp: string;
begin
 tmp:= PathVar;
  while Pos('\', tmp) > 0 do
    tmp[Pos('\', tmp)] := '/';
 result:= tmp;
end;

{ generates PostScript file from PDF file }
procedure PDF2PS(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
var
  ExitCode:integer;
  instance: Pointer;
  Arg: array of PAnsiChar;
begin
  ExitCode := gsapi_new_instance(instance, nil);
  if ExitCode < 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Impossible to open an instance of ghostscript. Error ExitCode: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
  try
    SetLength(Arg, 7);
    Arg[0] := PAnsiChar('-q');
    arg[1] := PAnsiChar('-dSAFER');
    Arg[2] := PAnsiChar('-dNOPAUSE');
    arg[3] := PAnsiChar('-dBATCH');
    arg[4] := PAnsiChar('-sOutputFile=' + output + '.ps');
    arg[5] := PAnsiChar('-sDEVICE=ps2write');
    arg[6] := PAnsiChar(input);

    ExitCode := gsapi_init_with_args(instance, Length(Arg), @Arg[0]);
    if ExitCode < 0 then raise Exception.Create('ERROR: init_args: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
    gsapi_exit(instance);
  finally
    gsapi_delete_instance(instance);
  end;
end;

{ generates PDF file from PostScript file }
procedure PS2PDF(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
var
  ExitCode:integer;
  instance: Pointer;
  Arg: array of PAnsiChar;
begin
  ExitCode := gsapi_new_instance(instance, nil);
  if ExitCode < 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Impossible to open an instance of ghostscript. Error ExitCode: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
  try
  SetLength(Arg, 9);
    Arg[0] := PAnsiChar('ps2pdf');
    arg[1] := PAnsiChar('-dNOPAUSE');
    arg[2] := PAnsiChar('-dBATCH');
    arg[3] := PAnsiChar('-dSAFER');
    arg[4] := PAnsiChar('-sDEVICE=pdfwrite');
    arg[5] := PAnsiChar('-sOutputFile='+ output+'.pdf');
    arg[6] := PAnsiChar('-c');
    arg[7] := PAnsiChar('.setpdfwrite');
    arg[8] := PAnsiChar('-f' + input);

    ExitCode := gsapi_init_with_args(instance, Length(Arg), @Arg[0]);
    if ExitCode < 0 then raise Exception.Create('ERROR: init_args: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
    gsapi_exit(instance);
  finally
    gsapi_delete_instance(instance);
  end;
end;

{ generates JPEG image from PDF - 1 image per page }
procedure PDF2JPEG(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
var
  ExitCode:integer;
  instance: Pointer;
  Arg: array of PAnsiChar;
begin
  ExitCode := gsapi_new_instance(instance, nil);
  if ExitCode < 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Impossible to open an instance of ghostscript. Error ExitCode: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
  try
    SetLength(Arg, 16);
    Arg[0]  := PAnsiChar('-q');
    Arg[1]  := PAnsiChar('-dQUIET');
    Arg[2]  := PAnsiChar('-dPARANOIDSAFER');
    Arg[3]  := PAnsiChar('-dBATCH');
    Arg[4]  := PAnsiChar('-dNOPAUSE');
    Arg[5]  := PAnsiChar('-dNOPROMPT');
    Arg[6]  := PAnsiChar('-dMaxBitmap=500000000');
    Arg[7]  := PAnsiChar('-dFirstPage=1');
    Arg[8]  := PAnsiChar('-dAlignToPixels=0');
    Arg[9]  := PAnsiChar('-dGridFitTT=0');
    Arg[10] := PAnsiChar('-sDEVICE=jpeg');
    Arg[11] := PAnsiChar('-dTextAlphaBits=4');
    Arg[12] := PAnsiChar('-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4');
    Arg[13] := PAnsiChar('-r300x300');
    Arg[14] := PAnsiChar('-sOutputFile='+ output + ' Page-%02d.jpeg' );
    Arg[15] := PAnsiChar(input);

    ExitCode := gsapi_init_with_args(instance, Length(Arg), @Arg[0]);
    if ExitCode < 0 then raise Exception.Create('ERROR: init_args: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
    gsapi_exit(instance);
  finally
    gsapi_delete_instance(instance);
  end;
end;

{ extracts plain text from PDF file via ps2ascii.ps interpreter}
{ another interpreter is pstotxt.ps floating on the internet }
procedure PDS2TXT(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
var
  ExitCode:integer;
  instance: Pointer;
  Arg: array of PAnsiChar;
  PSInterpreter: string;
  OutputFile: string;
begin
input:= SlashSwap(input);
{*note: place your interpreter in your .EXE project folder }
PSInterpreter:= ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'ps2ascii.ps';
PSInterpreter:= SlashSwap(PSInterpreter);
outputFile:= ExtractFilePath(input) + output + '.txt';
OutputFile:= SlashSwap(OutputFile);
output:= OutputFile;

  ExitCode := gsapi_new_instance(instance, nil);
  if ExitCode < 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Impossible to open an instance of ghostscript. Error ExitCode: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
  try
    SetLength(Arg, 9);
    Arg[0]  := PAnsiChar('-q');
    Arg[1]  := PAnsiChar('-sstdout='+ output); { Your_TXT_File_Out.txt }
    Arg[2]  := PAnsiChar('-dSIMPLE');
    Arg[3]  := PAnsiChar('-sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts');
    Arg[4]  := PAnsiChar('-dNODISPLAY');
    Arg[5]  := PAnsiChar('-dDELAYBIND');
    Arg[6]  := PAnsiChar('-dWRITESYSTEMDICT');
    Arg[7]  := PAnsiChar('-f'+ PSInterpreter); { path/to/ps2ascii.ps }
    Arg[8]  := PAnsiChar(input); { Your_PDF_File_In.pdf }

    ExitCode := gsapi_init_with_args(instance, Length(Arg), @Arg[0]);
    if ExitCode < 0 then raise Exception.Create('ERROR: init_args: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
    gsapi_exit(instance);
  finally
    gsapi_delete_instance(instance);
  end;
end;

{ extract plain text from PDF File via TxtWrite device }
procedure PDF2TXT(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
var   ExitCode:integer;
  instance: Pointer;
      Arg: array of PAnsiChar;
begin
  ExitCode := gsapi_new_instance(instance, nil);
  if ExitCode < 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Impossible to open an instance of ghostscript. Error ExitCode: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
  try
    SetLength(Arg, 5);
    Arg[0] := PAnsiChar('-dBATCH');
    Arg[1] := PAnsiChar('-dNOPAUSE');
    Arg[2] := PAnsiChar('-sDEVICE=txtwrite');
    Arg[3] := PAnsiChar('-sOutputFile='+ output + '.txt' );
    Arg[4] := PAnsiChar(input);

    ExitCode := gsapi_init_with_args(instance, Length(Arg), @Arg[0]);
    if ExitCode < 0 then raise Exception.Create('ERROR: init_args: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
    gsapi_exit(instance);
  finally
    gsapi_delete_instance(instance);
  end;
end;

{ generates PNG image from PDF - 1 image per page }
procedure PDF2PNG(input : AnsiString; output: AnsiString);
var
  ExitCode:integer;
  instance: Pointer;
  Arg: array of PAnsiChar;
begin
  ExitCode := gsapi_new_instance(instance, nil);
  if ExitCode < 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Impossible to open an instance of ghostscript. Error ExitCode: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
  try
    SetLength(Arg, 11);
    Arg[0] := PAnsiChar('ps2pdf');
    Arg[1] := PAnsiChar('-dNOPAUSE');
    Arg[2] := PAnsiChar('-dBATCH');
    Arg[3] := PAnsiChar('-dSAFER');
    Arg[4] := PAnsiChar('-sDEVICE=pngalpha');
    Arg[5] := PAnsiChar('-r300');
    Arg[6] := PAnsiChar('-dTextAlphaBits=4');
    Arg[7] := PAnsiChar('-sOutputFile='+output+' Page-%02d.png');
    Arg[8] := PAnsiChar('-c');
    Arg[9] := PAnsiChar('.setpdfwrite');
    Arg[10]:= PAnsiChar('-f'+ input);

    ExitCode := gsapi_init_with_args(instance, Length(Arg), @Arg[0]);
    if ExitCode < 0 then raise Exception.Create('ERROR: init_args: '+IntToStr(ExitCode));
    gsapi_exit(instance);
  finally
    gsapi_delete_instance(instance);
  end;
end;

end.
```

If you make it better, send me a copy ;-)